# Cython function with variable sized matrix input

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I am trying to convert part of a native python function to cython to improve the compute time. I would like to write a cython function just for the loop component that is taking up the time (as ipython lprun kindly told me). However this function takes in variably sized matrices .. and I can't see how to bring that across easily to statically typed cython.

```
for index1 in range(0,num_products):
    for index2 in range(0,num_products):
        cond_prob = (data[index1] * data[index2]).sum() / max(col_sums[index1], col_sums[index2])
        prox[index1][index2] = cond_prob
```

This issue is that num_products changes year to year, so the matrix (data) size is variable.

What is the best strategy here?

1. Should I write two C functions. One to create a matrix of a certain dimension using memalloc, and then One to do the loops over the created matrix?
2. Is there some fancy cython/numpy wizardry to help in this scenario? Can I write a C function that takes in a variably sized Numpy Array in memory and pass the size?

Comment: Hi also in cython you could do stuff like num_products = data.shape[0] or similar so the length of your loop will be adapted for you. However I'm not quite sure the way you are about to do improve your loop will help very much, because you are using numpy functions inside you cython loop. what you are trying to do seems very much straight forward in numpy as well... is the above expression your original python code? because if it is you could optimize it by leaving out the for loops and thus make it much faster.

Comment: A few questions: What is the `shape` of the arrays `data` and `prox`? Are they both numpy arrays? How large is `num_products` typically?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Good point re: vectorizing rather than looping over the numpy arrays! data = (170 x 800) and prox is therefore 800 x 800

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cython code is (strategically) statically typed, but that doesn't mean that arrays must have a fixed size. In straight C passing a multidimensional array to a function can be a little awkward maybe, but in Cython you should be able to do something like the following:

Note I took the function and variable names from your [follow-up question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22853837/2379410)

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
def cooccurance_probability_cy(double[:,:] X):
    cdef int P, i, j, k
    P = X.shape[0]
    cdef double item
    cdef double [:] CS = np.sum(X, axis=1)
    cdef double [:,:] D = np.empty((P, P), dtype=np.float)

    for i in range(P):
        for j in range(P):
            item = 0
            for k in range(P):
                item += X[i,k] * X[j,k]
            D[i,j] = item / max(CS[i], CS[j])
    return D
```

On the other hand, using just Numpy should also be quite fast for this problem, if you use the right functions and some broadcasting. In fact, as the calculation complexity is dominated by the matrix multiplication, I found the following is much faster than the Cython code above (`np.inner` uses a highly optimized BLAS routine):

```
def new(X):
    CS = np.sum(X, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    D = np.inner(X,X) / np.maximum(CS, CS.T)
    return D
```

Comment: Excellent explanation re: Cython ... I have update the follow-up question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22853837/why-doesnt-numba-improve-this-iteration) with your Cython Function

Comment: @sanguineturtle, In the meantime I edited my answer: Turns out that disabling bounds checking for the Cython function results in significantly better performance. I also found that the plain Numpy one is faster still, you should definitely check that out `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried getting rid of the for loops in numpy?

for the first part of your equation you could for example try:

```
(data[ np.newaxis,:] * data[:,np.newaxis]).sum(2)
```

if memory is an issue you can also use the np.einsum() function.
For the second part one could probably also cook up a numpy expression (bit more difficult) if you've not already tried that.

Comment: Great Idea! ... I will try this tomorrow and update this post